# Django object.filter returns Object (1) on search bar

Tags: python, html, django

So I have a Django website Project that contains a database of all the different books stored in it. With my search bar, if I type in the name it will show results from the database. The problem is that whenever I type in said name (***One Piece or Attack On Titan***), instead of showing its title name, it will either show ***Book Object (1)*** or ***Book Object (2)*** depending on what name I type and I don't know why.

This is where I defined my classes:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    editor = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    year_published = models.IntegerField()
    number_in_stock = models.IntegerField()
    daily_rate = models.FloatField(null=True)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    manga_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')
```

And this is where I defined my requests:

```
def search_manga(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        searched = request.POST[('searched')]
        mangas = Book.objects.filter(title__contains=searched)
        return render(request, 'books/search_manga.html', {'searched': searched, 'mangas': mangas})
    else:
        return render(request,'books/search_manga.html', {})
```

Also this is the HTML document I'm trying to show the results on:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <style>
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    {% if searched %}
        <h1>You Searched For {{searched}}</h1>
        <br/>
        {% for manga in mangas %}
            {{ manga }}<br/>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <h1>Hey! You Forgot To Search For A Manga</h1>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock  %}
```

Please note I'm very new to Django by the way.

Comment: please share your template `'books/search_manga.html'`

Comment: Ik you've already got an answer, but also look into model `__str__` methods.. You can set it to something more pretty than `{model} Object ({PK})` like `Book: {title}` or really anything.. It'll show anytime you do `{{bookobj}}` in templates or print in the shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `render()` method is returning a QuerySet of Books (`mangas`) to the template. You need to [iterate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for) over this set of books, and render the attributes you care about in your template like so:

```
{% for x in mangas %}
    name is {{ x.title }}
{% endfor %}
```